# phaser 3 Trying to make bullet travel towards a location

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

i am trying to make my bullet travel towards the cursor location. I have tried lots of things and I just can't get it to work. I have the player arm set up to always move to the player shoulder level. The player's arm and the gun has the same rotation value. The rotation value is calculated using `Phaser.Math.Angle.BetweenPoints(playerArm, player1Aim);`. I found a couple examples but i couldn't get them to work. Please teach me how to use it. I am a newbie. Please help. Here is my code:

```
    var config = {
        type: Phaser.AUTO,
        width: 512,
        height: 512,
        physics: {
            default: 'arcade',
            arcade: {
                gravity: {
                    y: 1500
                },
                debug: false
            }
        },
        scene: {
            preload: preload,
            create: create,
            update: update
        }

        // plugins: {
        //     global: [{
        //         key: 'PhaserPauseRenderPlugin',
        //         plugin: PhaserPauseRenderPlugin,
        //         mapping: 'render'
        //     }]
        // }

    };

    // class SceneMain extends Phaser.Scene {
    //     constructor() {
    //         super('SceneMain');
    //     }
    //     preload() {}
    //     create() {

    //         //make 3 bars
    //         let healthBar = this.makeBar(140, 100, 0x2ecc71);
    //         this.setValue(healthBar, 100);


    //         // let powerBar = this.makeBar(140, 200, 0xe74c3c);
    //         // this.setValue(powerBar, 50);


    //         // let magicBar = this.makeBar(140, 300, 0x2980b9);
    //         // this.setValue(magicBar, 33);

    //     }
    //     makeBar(x, y, color) {
    //         //draw the bar
    //         let bar = this.add.graphics();

    //         //color the bar
    //         bar.fillStyle(color, 1);

    //         //fill the bar with a rectangle
    //         bar.fillRect(0, 0, 200, 50);

    //         //position the bar
    //         bar.x = x;
    //         bar.y = y;

    //         //return the bar
    //         return bar;
    //     }
    //     setValue(bar, percentage) {
    //         //scale the bar
    //         bar.scaleX = percentage / 100;
    //     }
    //     update() {}
    // }

    var player;
    var platforms;
    var cursors;
    var gameOver = false;
    var score = 0;
    var time;
    var waves;
    var enemies;
    var enemy;
    var health;
    var hacking = false;
    var timer;
    var enemyCount = 0;
    var startGame = false;
    var timeSpeed = 1;
    var keys;
    var damageStrike = 0;
    var toMouse = 0;
    var toPlayer = 0;
    var bullets;
    var ship;
    var speed;
    var stats;
    var cursors;
    var lastFired = 0;
    var fire = false;
    var pointerDown = false;

    // var healthBar = new SceneMain();

    // spaceBar input
    // var spaceBar = Phaser.Input.Keyboard.KeyCodes.SPACE;

    var game = new Phaser.Game(config);

    function preload() {
        //this.load.image('platform', 'images/platform.png');
        // this.load.image('background', 'images/background.png');z
        this.load.image('background', 'images/background.png');
        this.load.image('platform', 'images/platform.png');
        this.load.image('longPlatform', 'images/platform long.png');
        this.load.image('itembg', 'images/item bg.png');
        this.load.image('playerArm', 'images/player arm.png');
        this.load.image('enemyArm', 'images/enemy arm.png');
        this.load.image('playerGun', 'images/player gun.png');
        this.load.image('enemyGun', 'images/enemy gun.png');
        this.load.image('medkit', 'images/medkit.png');
        this.load.image('aim', 'images/aim.png');
        this.load.image('bullet', 'images/laser.png');


        this.load.spritesheet('player', 'images/player idle-1.png', {
            frameWidth: 49,
            frameHeight: 128
        });
        this.load.spritesheet('enemy', 'images/enemy.png', {
            frameWidth: 49,
            frameHeight: 128
        });




    }



    function create() {

        // var Bullet = new Phaser.Class({

        //     Extends: Phaser.GameObjects.Image,

        //     initialize:

        //     // Bullet Constructor
        //         function Bullet(scene) {
        //         Phaser.GameObjects.Image.call(this, scene, 0, 0, 'bullet');
        //         this.speed = 1;
        //         this.born = 0;
        //         this.direction = 0;
        //         this.xSpeed = 0;
        //         this.ySpeed = 0;
        //         this.setSize(12, 12, true);
        //     },

        //     // Fires a bullet from the player to the reticle
        //     fire: function(player, target) {
        //         this.setPosition(player.x, player.y); // Initial position
        //         this.direction = Math.atan((target.x - this.x) / (target.y - this.y));

        //         // Calculate X and y velocity of bullet to moves it from shooter to target
        //         if (target.y >= this.y) {
        //             this.xSpeed = this.speed * Math.sin(this.direction);
        //             this.ySpeed = this.speed * Math.cos(this.direction);
        //         } else {
        //             this.xSpeed = -this.speed * Math.sin(this.direction);
        //             this.ySpeed = -this.speed * Math.cos(this.direction);
        //         }


        //         this.rotation = player.rotation; // angle bullet with shooters rotation
        //         this.born = 0; // Time since new bullet spawned
        //     },

        //     // Updates the position of the bullet each cycle
        //     update: function(time, delta) {
        //         this.x += this.xSpeed * delta;
        //         this.y += this.ySpeed * delta;
        //         this.born += delta;
        //         if (this.born > 500) {
        //             this.setActive(false);
        //             this.setVisible(false);
        //         }
        //     }

        // });

        // playerBullets = this.physics.add.group({
        //     classType: Bullet,
        //     runChildUpdate: true
        // });

        speed = Phaser.Math.GetSpeed(300, 1);


        // healthBar.makeBar(32, 32, 0xffffff);

        // console.log(timer);

        // add background
        // this.add.image(256, 256, 'background');

        background = this.add.image(256, 256, 'background');
        background.alpha = 0.8;

        itemBg = this.add.image(256, 520, 'itembg')

        platforms = this.physics.add.staticGroup();

        //  Here we create the ground.

        platforms.create(256, 450, 'longPlatform').refreshBody();;


        // platforms.create(256, 450, 'platform');
        platforms.create(50, 175, 'platform');
        platforms.create(460, 175, 'platform');
        platforms.create(50, 350, 'platform');
        platforms.create(460, 350, 'platform');
        platforms.create(265, 250, 'platform');


        player = this.physics.add.sprite(256, 10, 'player');
        player.setScale(0.5);
        player.setBounce(0.1);
        player.setCollideWorldBounds(true);

        playerArm = this.add.image(256, 256, 'playerArm');
        playerArm.setScale(0.5);
        playerArm.angle = 0;

        playerGun = this.add.image(256, 256, 'playerGun');
        playerGun.setScale(0.5);
        playerGun.angle = 0;

        enemyArm = this.add.image(256, 256, 'enemyArm');
        enemyArm.setScale(0.5);
        enemyArm.angle = 0;

        enemyGun = this.add.image(256, 256, 'enemyGun');
        enemyGun.setScale(0.5);
        enemyGun.angle = 0;

        player1Aim = this.add.image(256, 256, 'aim');
        player1Aim.setScale(2);
        player1Aim.angle = 0;

        bullet = this.add.image(256, 10, 'bullet');
        bullet.setScale(0.25);
        bullet.angle = 0;

        var playerX = player.x;
        var playerY = player.y;

        enemies = this.physics.add.group();
        medkits = this.physics.add.group();

        spawn = (x, enemyName) => {
            enemyPlayer = this.physics.add.sprite(x, 20, enemyName);
            // enemyPlayer = this.physics.add.sprite.destroy(true);
            console.log(enemyPlayer);
            enemyPlayer.setScale(0.5);
            enemyPlayer.setBounce(0.1);
            enemyPlayer.setCollideWorldBounds(true);
            enemyPlayer.allowGravity = true;
            return enemyPlayer;
        }

        spawnMedkit = (x, enemyName) => {
            enemyPlayer = this.physics.add.sprite(x, 20, enemyName);
            // enemyPlayer = this.physics.add.sprite.destroy(true);
            console.log(enemyPlayer);
            enemyPlayer.setScale(1);
            enemyPlayer.setBounce(0.1);
            enemyPlayer.setCollideWorldBounds(true);
            enemyPlayer.allowGravity = true;
            return enemyPlayer;
        }



        enemy = spawn(450, 'enemy');
        medkit = spawnMedkit(100, 'medkit');
        enemyCount += 1;
        console.log(enemyCount);

        // enemy = enemies.create(450, 20, 'enemy')

        // // enemies.create(250, 20, 'enemy')

        // enemy.setScale(0.5)
        // enemy.setBounce(0.1);
        // enemy.setCollideWorldBounds(true);
        // enemy.allowGravity = true;



        cursors = this.input.keyboard.createCursorKeys();

        this.physics.add.collider(player, platforms);
        this.physics.add.collider(enemy, platforms);
        this.physics.add.collider(medkit, platforms);
        // this.physics.add.collider(bombs, platforms);

        health = 100;
        waves = 0;

        // timer = this.time.create(false);

        //  The score
        scoreText = this.add.text(16, 16, 'score: 0', {
            fontSize: '25px',
            fill: '#00FFFF'
        });

        // FPS
        fps = this.add.text(16, 50, game.loop.actualFps, {
            fontSize: '15px',
            fill: '#00FFFF'
        });

        timeScale = this.add.text(16, 70, this.physics.world.timeScale, {
            fontSize: '15px',
            fill: '#00FFFF'
        });

        gunRotation = this.add.text(16, 100, 'gun rotation: 0', {
            fontSize: '15px',
            fill: '#00FFFF'
        });


        // gameStatus = this.add.text(16, 60, 'Game Status: Alive', {
        //     fontSize: '25px',
        //     fill: '#00FFFF'
        // });

        // hp = this.add.text(16, 100, 'Health: ' + health, {
        //     fontSize: '25px',
        //     fill: '#00FFFF'
        // });

        // add collisions
        this.physics.add.collider(player, enemy, damage, null, this);
        this.physics.add.collider(player, medkit, healByMedkit, null, this);
        // this.physics.add.collider(laser, enemy, hit, null, this);


        keys = this.input.keyboard.addKeys('W,A,S,D,F,J,K,L,SPACE');

        var r1 = this.add.rectangle(playerX, playerY - 15, 200, 69, 10, 0x6666ff);

        this.input.on('pointermove', function(pointer) {
            toMouse = Phaser.Math.Angle.BetweenPoints(playerArm, player1Aim);
        });

        this.input.on('pointerdown', function(pointer) {
            // shoot the bullet towards the cursor (player1Aim)
        });

        startGame = true;



    }

    function update(time, delta) {

        var playerX = player.x;
        var playerY = player.y;
        var enemyX = enemy.x;
        var enemyY = enemy.y;
        var playerArmX = playerArm.x;
        var playerArmY = playerArm.y;
        var playerArmRotation = playerArm.angle;
        var mouseX = game.input.mousePointer.x;
        var mouseY = game.input.mousePointer.y;
        // var theta =

        // console.log(playerArmRotation);

        // position the arm to the shoulder level of the player
        playerArm.x = playerX;
        playerArm.y = playerY - 5;

        playerGun.x = playerX;
        playerGun.y = playerY - 3;

        enemyArm.x = enemyX;
        enemyArm.y = enemyY - 5;

        enemyGun.x = enemyX;
        enemyGun.y = enemyY - 5;

        player1Aim.x = mouseX;
        player1Aim.y = mouseY;



        toPlayer = Phaser.Math.Angle.BetweenPoints(enemy, player);


        playerArm.rotation = Phaser.Math.Angle.BetweenPoints(playerArm, player1Aim);
        playerGun.rotation = Phaser.Math.Angle.BetweenPoints(playerArm, player1Aim);

        enemyArm.rotation = toPlayer;
        enemyGun.rotation = toPlayer;

        // rotate gun for player
        if (playerGun.angle >= 90 || playerGun.angle <= -90) {
            playerGun.flipY = true;
            // console.log('flipped')
        } else {
            playerGun.flipY = false;
        }

        // rotate gun for player
        if (enemyGun.angle >= 90 || enemyGun.angle <= -90) {
            enemyGun.flipY = true;
            // console.log('flipped')
        } else {
            enemyGun.flipY = false;
        }





        // this.input.on('pointerdown', function(pointer) {
        //     if (pointerDown == false) {
        //         pointerDown = true;
        //         fire();
        //         console.log('FIRE');
        //     } else {
        //         pointerDown = false;
        //     }
        // });

        // this.input.on('pointerdown', function(pointer, time, lastFired) {
        //     if (player.active === false)
        //         return;

        //     // Get bullet from bullets group
        //     var bullet = playerBullets.get().setActive(true).setVisible(true);

        //     if (bullet) {
        //         bullet.fire(playerGun, player1Aim);
        //         // this.physics.add.collider(enemy, bullet, enemyHitCallback);
        //     }
        // }, this);



        // this.input.on('pointerdown', function(pointer) {
        //     if (time > lastFired) {
        //         var bullet = bullets.get();
        //         console.log('test2');
        //         if (bullet) {
        //             // bullet.rotation = playerGun.rotation;
        //             bullet.fire(playerGun.x, playerGun.y);
        //             lastFired = time + 50;
        //         }
        //     }
        // });






        if (startGame == true) {

            if (keys.J.isDown) {
                this.physics.world.timeScale = 1.75;
                // console.log(this.physics.world.timeScale);
                // timeSpeed = 0.5;
                // console.log(timeSpeed);
            } else

            if (keys.K.isDown) {
                this.physics.world.timeScale = 0.75;
                // timeSpeed = 1;
            }

            if (keys.L.isDown) {

            }




            if (gameOver) {
                return;
                gameStatus.setText('Game Status: Dead')
            }

            if (cursors.left.isDown || keys.A.isDown) {
                player.setVelocityX(-160 * timeSpeed);

            } else if (cursors.right.isDown || keys.D.isDown) {
                player.setVelocityX(160 * timeSpeed);

            } else {
                player.setVelocityX(0 * timeSpeed);

            }

            if (cursors.up.isDown && player.body.touching.down) {
                player.setVelocityY(-650 * timeSpeed);
            }

            if (keys.W.isDown && player.body.touching.down) {
                player.setVelocityY(-650 * timeSpeed);
            }

            if (keys.SPACE.isDown && player.body.touching.down) {
                player.setVelocityY(-650 * timeSpeed);
            }

            if (waves == 0) {
                waves += 1;
                console.log(waves)
            }



            fps.setText('fps: ' + game.loop.actualFps);
            scoreText.setText('Score: ' + score);
            timeScale.setText('timeScale: ' + this.physics.world.timeScale);
            gunRotation.setText('gun rotation: ' + playerGun.angle);
        }



    }

    function damage(player, enemy) {
        enemy.disableBody(true, true);
        // enemy.body.enable = false;
        // enemy.body.gameObject.active = false;
        enemyCount -= 1;
        console.log(enemyCount);
        health -= 10;
        score -= 10;
        damageStrike += 1;


        if (enemyCount === 0) {
            var randomX = Phaser.Math.FloatBetween(0, 500);
            enemy.enableBody(true, randomX, 15, true, true);
            enemyCount += 1;
            console.log(enemyCount);
        }

        if (damageStrike === 3 && medkits.countActive(false) == 0) {
            var randomX = Phaser.Math.FloatBetween(0, 500);
            medkit.enableBody(true, randomX, 15, true, true);
            damageStrike = 0;

        }

        console.log('Health: ' + health);

        if (health <= 0) {
            gameOver = true;
        }
    }

    function hit(laser, enemy) {
        score += 10;
        enemy.disableBody(true, true);
    }

    function healByMedkit(player, medkit) {
        score += 5;
        health += 15;
        console.log(health);
        medkit.disableBody(true, true);
    }
```

Comment: Hello @Leo Yu, just for future reference you should only post the minial code needed to see the problem. like defined [in this Stackoverflow article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). If that is not possible atleast remove the commented code. That makes helping easier for everybody.

Comment: Hi @winner_joiner, thank so much for helping me!. Sorry for inconvenience though. I am really new to this community. But thank you from the bottom of my heart that you are willing to spend time to help me! You helped me a lot!

Comment: No Problem, I assumed you are new, that's why I just wanted to give you a tip, how to get answers faster. :) btw.: if my solution help you, please consider upvotng or accepting it with the green check mark. This helps me and other to see that answer is helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well if you want to rotate a *gameObjects* and shoot something in a specific angle, in Phaser you should have to keep somethings in mind:

1. Origin of the gameObject *(since the rotation occurs around this point)*
2. The direction / angle offset of the *gameObject* you want to rotate

Apart from that, everything is more or less straightforward, calculate the vector for "shooting" a bullet and set the velocity of that bullet.

**Here a short demo:**
In this Demo, the both main factors are shown, `origin` and "angle-offset".
*(It should cover the basic from your code)*

```js
document.body.style = 'margin:0;';

var config = {
    type: Phaser.AUTO,
    width: 536,
    height: 183,
    physics: {
        default: 'arcade',
        arcade: {            
            gravity:{ y: 50 },
        }
    },
    scene: {
        create,
        update
    },
    banner: false
}; 

function create () {
    
    this.add.text(10, 10, 'Click to shoot bullets')
      .setOrigin(0);
    
    // head
    this.add.circle ( 42, 60, 8, 0xffffff)
      .setOrigin(0);
    
    // body
    let player = this.add.rectangle( 40, 80, 20, 50, 0xffffff)
      .setOrigin(0);
    
    // sholder
    this.add.circle ( 50, 90, 5, 0xff0000)
      .setOrigin(0.5);
    
    // arm
    let playerArm = this.add.rectangle( 50, 90, 10, 30, 0xff0000)
      // Point #1: the Point of rotation is more or less the shoulder
      .setOrigin(.5, 0)
      .setDepth(10); 
    
    // create bullet Group
    this.bullets = this.add.group();
    
    this.input.on('pointermove', pointer => {
          let rotation = Phaser.Math.Angle.BetweenPoints(playerArm, pointer);
          // Point #2: Angle-Offset since the 0 Degrees is on the right, 
          // and the arm is pointing down I need to subtract 90° 0 PI/2
          playerArm.rotation = rotation - Math.PI / 2;
    });
      
      this.input.on('pointerdown', pointer => {
          let speed = 300;
          
          // create bullet
          let bullet = this.add.circle( playerArm.x, playerArm.y, 4, 0xffff00)
            .setDepth(9); 
          this.physics.add.existing(bullet);
          
          // get Vector where to shoot bullet
          let vector = new Phaser.Math.Vector2( pointer.x - playerArm.x, pointer.y - playerArm.y );
           
          // set Speed of bullet 
          vector.setLength(speed);
          
          // DEMO: to shoot in a straightline, just comment the following line in
          // bullet.body.setAllowGravity(false);
          
          // DEMO: QuickFix to destroy the bullet after 1 Second automatically
          // setTimeout( () => bullet.destroy(), 1000);
          
          // add bullet to group
          this.bullets.add(bullet);
          
          bullet.body.setVelocity(vector.x, vector.y);
      });
}

function update(){
  this.bullets.getChildren().forEach(bullet => {
      if(bullet.x > config.width){
        bullet.destroy();
      }
  })
}

new Phaser.Game(config);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/phaser@3.55.2/dist/phaser.js"></script>
```

> If you want the bullet to fly without gravity / in a **straight line**, just add this line `bullet.body.setAllowGravity(false);` after the creation of the bullet, to turn off the physics effect for the bullet.

Comment: Hi there, the codes work very well! But the problem now is the bullet created doesn't seem to disappear which causes significant game lag. Is there any way solve that?

Comment: @LeoYu I updated the answer with a solution, using Phaser `Groups`, it needs several extra lines of code. On the otherhand you could only use a simple _quick_ fix, just add the line `setTimeout( () =>bullet.destroy(), 1000);` after the bullet creation, and the bullet will be destroyed 1 second after creation. It's not as clean as the abouve solution, but depending on the usecase it might be better.

Comment: Hi again, there is another problem. When I made it so it would trigger a function when it overlap with the enemy, I found that some bullets got reflected. I quickly wrote a code to test it, it turns out there more than one bullets fired. This also made it unable to keep track of number of bullets alive.

Comment: @LeoYu if you are using `pointerdown`, only one bullet should be created for each click (except may be if you are using a mobil device) if you are using a `group` you can get the bullets count with the function `getLength()`. You could even use group functions too limit the amount of bullets with `maxSize`, that could be fired at once. (checkout this [example](https://phaser.io/examples/v3/view/game-objects/group/sprite-pool) for more details). If this doesn't help, I would recommend, creating a new question with the relevant parts of code, since the issue could be in so many different places.