# Phaser 3 Trying to trace number of bullets active

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

I am trying to make my bullet into `group`. I am beginner at phaser 3. I got my bullet working from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73932768/phaser-3-trying-to-make-bullet-travel-towards-a-location). I want to make the bullets created be traceable.

There is another problem. After some short tests I found out that there are multiple bullets created. Test 1: I added barriers on the outside of the scene and added collider with the bullet and the barriers, it logged multiple times when triggered. Test 2: When having contact with the enemy, some bullets got reflect and flew the other way. This is related to the question because this can be done by limiting the bullets if there is some way to trace them.

Click [here](https://Neon-City-1.leoiscoding.repl.co) for the full code on replit.

```
this.input.on('pointerdown', pointer => {
    if (ammo > 0) {
        charge.setText('CHARGED!');
        let speed = 750;
        console.log(ammo);

        // create bullet
        bullet = this.add.image(playerArm.x, playerArm.y, 'bullet');
        bullet.setScale(0.5);
        bullet.rotation = playerArm.rotation;
        this.physics.add.existing(bullet);

        group = this.add.group({
            defaultKey: 'bullet',
            maxSize: 100,
        })

        // get Vector where to shoot bullet
        let vector = new Phaser.Math.Vector2(pointer.x - playerArm.x, pointer.y - playerArm.y);

        // set Speed of bullet 
        vector.setLength(speed * timeSpeed);

        // QuickFix to destroy the bullet after 1 Second automatically
        setTimeout(() => bullet.destroy(), 1500);
        ammo -= 1;

        // to shoot in a straightline, just comment the following line in
        // bullet.body.setAllowGravity(false);
        function killBullet() {
            bullet.destroy();
        }


        bullet.body.setVelocity(vector.x, vector.y);
        bullet.body.setAllowGravity(false);
        bulletsAlive.setText('Bullets alive' + group.getLength())
        this.physics.add.collider(bullet, enemy, hitEnemy, null, this);
        this.physics.add.collider(bullet, platforms, killBullet, null, this);
    }
});

if (ammo <= 0) {
    function onEvent() {
        ammo = 15;
    }
    timedEvent = this.time.delayedCall(2000, onEvent, [], this);
    // setTimeout(() => ammo = 15, 1000);
    charge.setText('OUT OF CHARGE! CHARGING!');
    console.log('reloading');
}
```

Comment: I just wanted to ask, did my answer help, or did I miss something?

Comment: sorry man, forgot to approve it ;-;. Your answer definitely helped!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The multiple bullet issue has to do with the fact, that `pointerdown`-event listener code is set in the `update` function *(the `update` function is called more or less **60 times per second** )*.

This means, every second about 60 event listerner are created and attached, so for each `click` event this eventlistener will be called serveral times. *(what also could cause performance issues, with the more time passes)*.

Just move this code from the `update` function:

```
   this.input.on('pointerdown', pointer => {
    if (ammo > 0) {
        charge.setText('CHARGED!');
        let speed = 750;
        console.log(ammo);
        // create bullet
        let bullet = this.add.image(playerArm.x, playerArm.y, 'bullet');
        bullet.setScale(0.5);
        bullet.rotation = playerArm.rotation;
        this.physics.add.existing(bullet);
        // get Vector where to shoot bullet
        let vector = new Phaser.Math.Vector2(pointer.x - playerArm.x, pointer.y - playerArm.y);
        vector.setLength(speed * timeSpeed);
        setTimeout(() => bullet.destroy(), 1500);
        ammo -= 1;
        // to shoot in a straightline, just comment the following line in
        // bullet.body.setAllowGravity(false);
        function killBullet() {
            bullet.destroy();
        }
        bullet.body.setVelocity(vector.x, vector.y);
        bullet.body.setAllowGravity(false);
        this.physics.add.collider(bullet, enemy, hitEnemy, null, this);
        this.physics.add.collider(bullet, platforms, killBullet, null, this);
    }
});
```

into the `create` function, and only one bullet will be created, **and** now the `ammo` variable should have an accurate bullet count.

> It seems this was your initial plan, since in the `create` function you have already an empty eventlistener for the `pointerdown` event:
> `this.input.on('pointerdown', function (pointer) {`
>     `// shoot the bullet towards the cursor (player1Aim)`
> `});`

> ***Tip:** I would recommend, deleting  all un-needed, un-used or duplicate code, since this will make development and debugging easier for you.*